# How to find a number that occurs the most in an array in less than O(n)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, algorithm

I've been working on some Coding Katas to improve my programming. The question I have is how can I solve this problem with ***less than*** O(n). My first thought was to use regex, but I ran into some problems as outlined below.

## Problem Definition

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function SimpleMode(arr) take
>   the array of numbers stored in arr and return the number that appears
>   most frequently (the mode). For example: if arr contains [10, 4, 5, 2,
>   4] the output should be 4. If there is more than one mode return the
>   one that appeared in the array first (ie. [5, 10, 10, 6, 5] should
>   return 5 because it appeared first). If there is no mode return -1.
>   The array will not be empty.

### O(n) Solution

Here is the O(n) solution that I was able to come up with:

```js
function simpleMode(set) {
  var counter = {};

  var most = set.reduce(function(most, value) {
    if (!counter[value]) {
      counter[value] = 0;
    }

    counter[value]++;

    if (!counter[most] || counter[value] > counter[most]) {
      most = value;
    }

    return most;

  }, -1);

  return (counter[most] === 1 ? -1 : most);
};

console.log(simpleMode([5, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

### Regex Solution so far:

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't meet the requirement of returning the value that first appeared with the greatest occurrence. As well, I feel like using `sort` is a bit of a cheat, but it should still be less than O(n).

```js
function simpleMode(set) {
  var values = set.sort().join('')
  var regex = new RegExp(/(\d)\1+/g);
  var matches = regex.exec(values);

  return (matches ? matches[1] : -1);
}

console.log(simpleMode([5, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

## Summary

- How can this problem be solved with less than O(n)?
- How could the regex solution be fixed to work?

Comment: `join` also has a price

Comment: @paxdiablo Very good point.. Would it be possible to solve this problem less than O(n) in another way?

Comment: You have to iterate through the array at least once. For example `.join` you used in your code does pass through the array once. I don't think you can reduce it any less than O(n). Using regex for this problem is an overkill and it can very well be computationally lot more expensive than doing it from first principles.

Comment: @RaviH Good point. I was hoping there was some kind of unconventional solution that wouldn't involve comparing values directly.

Comment: As pointed out above, you need to pass through the array to be able to determine which value occurs the most.  So intuitively your solution will always be close to O(n).  The only optimisation I can think of is a check to determine whether or not you've done enough work to eliminate any other candidates.  eg: If you have [1, 1, 1, 2, 3] you already know after checking 3 values that 1 is the winner without even needing to look at 2 or 3.

Comment: @Paul Now that's clever!

Comment: @Pete Mayyybe.  :-)  The catch is to make that check worthwhile, your arrays would need to be holding a lot of a few distinct values.  A true random array would see almost no benefit.  (Just thinking out loud...)  On the other hand; if your array were accompanied by some accurate statistical data (from previous data sets?) you might be able to get a winner by inspecting only a sample of the data...

Comment: To the downvoter, please comment on the downvote. I would like advice on how to improve my questions in clarity, structure, or any other ways to improve the overall quality of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an algorithm is impossible. Suppose any algorithm looks at fewer than n/2 elements of the array. Then if the elements that haven't been looked at are all the same, they'll be the most-common value.

So *any* algorithm that finds the most common element must always look at n/2 elements of the array, and so its time complexity must be at least O(n).